# What's the story of the shear face in the new Mac OS Catalina wallpaper?

Tags: geology, california

The new Mac OS boasts a beautiful default desktop background with the western tip of Santa Catalina Island.  The rock formation in the foreground looks like it was sliced on the diagonal with a power tool, but I assume this uninhabited side of the island hasn't actually been altered.  What accounts for this smooth rock face?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bedding plane, once horizontal, but geological forces have tilted it to the diagonal. The strata above have been eroded and washed into the sea, perhaps by a storm, leaving the ancient bedding plane exposed. Tilted strata are not unusual in very ancient rock formations.